# Divide by zero error input into Tkinter message for a calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling, calculator

I built a calculator in python and it works, except that if someone tries to a number divided by zero, they don't receive an "Invalid Syntax!" error in the calculator input. How could I make it so the message "Invalid Syntax!" shows in the calculator input?

```
 def equals(self):
  self.getandreplace()
  try: 
   self.value= eval(self.newtext)
  except SyntaxError or NameError:
   self.e.delete(0,END)
   self.e.insert(0,'Invalid Syntax!')
  else:
   self.e.delete(0,END)
   self.e.insert(0,self.value)
```

I have tried putting `except NameError or SyntaxError or ZeroDivisionError` but it doesn't work. The error only appears in the shell, not as "Invalid Syntax!".

Comment: `SyntaxError or NameError` must be `(SyntaxError, NameError)`.

Comment: @DYZ it works without it

Comment: No it does not. Try entering "a+1".

Comment: @DYZ oh, I just tried it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] you can't keep dumping your code here each time you have a problem.

Comment: @Nae I fixed it.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as Too Broad since the typical way to handle semantic and syntax errors is to build a tokenizer (aka lexical analyzer) and a parser that together generate an abstract syntax tree and then analyze the syntax tree for semantic errors. In other words, you would write a compiler. This is well beyond the scope of a single SO question. As an aside, using `eval` on user input is heavily frowned upon since there are many situations in which it would allow an untrusted user to perform unauthorized and potentially harmful actions. It's best avoided in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ZeroDivisionError` to the list of your exceptions:

```
except (SyntaxError, NameError, ZeroDivisionError):
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought you could do ' except SyntaxError or NameError or ZeroDivisionError '